# How can I create a file only if it's the first time the program runs?

Tags: c++, file, save, project, clion

I have to submit a project to my professor. He told us to upload only source files.

The text says:

> The zip file should be divided into the following folders:
>
> - src: contains all the source files and CMakeLists.txt to compile the project with CLion
> - input: all the input files needed

My program has a structure like:

```
int main () {
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("save.txt", ios::in);
    if (fin.is_open()) {
    // reads everything from the file
    } else {
        return 1;
    }

    // all the program

    fstream fout;
    fout.open("save.txt", ios::out);
    if (fout.is_open()) {
    // writes everything on the file
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

What can I do to make the program create the file the first time it runs, so that it doesn't quit?

I've tried putting at the top:

```
ofstream fout1;
fout1.open("save.txt", ios::out);
if (fout1.is_open()) fout1.close();
```

But it deletes everything from the file when it is launched.

Comment: ***input: all the input files needed*** To me that means you create the file outside of your program.

Comment: So should I create manually a save.txt file there and specify the path inside my program?

Comment: You are missing the code for read/write in place of comments. Do you have it?

Comment: What do you mean with "in place of comments" (Sorry I'm not English)?

Comment: Don't give up if you fail to open the input file - just execute the rest of the program as normal.

Comment: That's a really good idea. So if it fails opening the input file I just don't do anything so that the program will eventually create it by itself?

Comment: Well, that depends on what the program actually does, but that's the idea, yes.

Comment: I would expect your program to use a relative path from your source (or perhaps executable folder depending on the default CLion behavior) to the Input folder which contains the text file you created using your favorite text file editor.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `ifstream fin; fin.open(“save.txt”, ios::in);` to `ifstream fin(“save.txt”);`. Note that I removed `ios::in`; an `ifstream` is already set for input. Similarly, change `fstream fout; fout.open(“save.txt”, ios::out);` to `ofstream fout(“save.txt”);`.

Comment: Ok @PeteBecker, thank you.